# is it possible to add class inside a tag of title attribute(data-html= "true") Bootstrap 4 Tooltip?

Tags: bootstrap-4, tooltip

it's a normal **bootstrap tooltip with data-html="true"**.i want to declare a class inside the ul tag like **ul class="x"** of title attribute.this is the normal code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-html="true" title="<ul><li>At least 5 letters</li></ul>">
```

this is what **i want**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-html="true" title="<ul class="x"><li>At least 5 letters</li></ul>">
```

the issue is with the **inverted commas of title tag**.the title attribute seems to be **closed after the class="x" declaration**.how could i get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Single Quote

```
title="<ul class='x'>...</ul>"
```

#### Numeric Character Reference `&#34;`

```
title="<ul class=&#34;x&#34;>...<ul>"
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/80571/

Comment: it helped thnx!